# Grease Pencil Fill Tool: How to make the radius markers match the drawing plane?

Tags: grease-pencil

When using the fill tool and MMB dragging to adjust the gap closure radius size, the circles look like this if the drawing plane is set to "Top (X-Y)" :

[image]

I have the grease pencil orientation facing a camera, so I've already used the "Top (X-Y)" drawing plane. It technically still works as it seems the gap closure is actually spherical and not literal to the circular graphic, but it would be nice to have the graphic aligned properly for reference.

Ideally, it would look like this no matter what drawing plane was selected:

[image]

Am I perhaps missing a setting to have the gap closure radius guides follow the drawing plane?